# CNF: Remove SOME popup options (from the ones that are platform contributions)

Tags: java, popup, eclipse-rcp, popupmenu, cnf

I need to modify popup menus using CNF. I already read documentation about using action providers and about using "allowsPlatformContribution" to restrict options that are platform contributions. I already used some of these concepts sucessfully to add/remove popup options. But there is one thing I need to do and I don't know how:
Related to PLATFORM CONTRIBUTIONS, I mean declared by org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus (in my case they are standard options: "Validate", "Run As", "Debug As", "Profile As",
"Team", "Compare With", "Restore from Local History...", "Java EE Tools", "Source", "Configure") I just want to show two of them: "Team" and "Compare With" (with all their suboptions).
If using "allowsPlatformContribution=false", then ALL options are removed !. The only idea I have right know is to set this to false and to create an actionProvider for each of both options I need to show, but it seems a bit hard, because I have to add all the suboptions
in it (invoking the appropriate Eclipse action) !. Is that a good way to solve my problem ?. There is another way easier and better ?... I hope so.

Please help. Thanks a lot.
Rosa.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Activities to show/hide elements in the user interface (including menus).

What you have to do is create an Activity and bind it to the UI element. Then, when you enable/disable your activity the platform will automatically show/hide the element bind to it.

For more details on the exact implementation, check out this page:

[Eclipse Activities – Hide / Display certain UI elements](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/)